# jQuery Flot xaxis elements number

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Im trying to generate graph with jquery Flot.
This is the script Im using:

```
var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [
        { data: data2, label: observation_obj.concept_name}
    ], {
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true
        },
        yaxis: {
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%d.%m"
        }
    });
```

The result I'm getting is this:

http://i62.tinypic.com/25uk51z.png

My data is contains of two points, I dont know why in the x axis I see 4 points,

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle with your data? You can adapt this one: __http://jsfiddle.net/fMFKw/__

Answer (score 2):

The ticks on the x-axis are automatically generated so that they are evenly spaced on the axis. If you want to change that you can give flot an array of (in your case) timestamps which match the timestamps from your data (only examples here):

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%d.%m",
    ticks: [1383582043000, 1383682043000]
}
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) for more infos / examples.